# Can I upgrade my iOS using the iTunes restore, but not to the latest version?

Tags: upgrade, restore, ios, versions, ipsw

Right now, the latest version of iOS is 9.1. Mine is 8.1.2. Can I use the restore option in iTunes to install version 9.0.2 or do I have to update to 9.1 and then downgrade to 9.0.2?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211890/146294

Answer (score 3):

I just did this. Use [ipsw.me](https://ipsw.me) to download your version (9.0.2). You can restore from any version that's green. Red means Apple isn't signing it. Press & hold option when clicking Restore in iTunes. Select the downloaded `.ipsw`

Do note that time is of the essence. Once Apple stops signing the 9.0.2 firmware, you will be forced to upgrade to a current OS image.