# How to upgrade a 3rd generation iPad to IOS 7?

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade

I have a family member with a 3rd Gen iPad (a1416) currently running iOS 6. They need to install an app that requires iOS 7. When looking at the system upgrade page in settings, it shows iOS 9 which I believe isn't compatible and also would probably run pretty slow anyway.

Is it possible to upgrade this 3rd Gen iPad to iOS 7? How can we do that? Thanks!

PS: I've already looked at [Upgrade iPad to newer (but not latest) iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211887/upgrade-ipad-to-newer-but-not-latest-ios?rq=1) but the site mentioned in the answer there doesn't offer a signed iOS 7 image.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't easily since Apple has stopped signing iOS 7, but I won't submit this as an answer since I've seen some places say it's possible via a series of tricks. I'm no expert in this field though, so I can't say what's valid and what's not.

Comment: Actually, I updated my brother-in-law's iPhone 4 about two weeks ago to iOS 7, but I suppose a lot can change in a fortnight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices has a list of which devices can run which iOS. You'll see the iPhone 4 is the only device that can run iOS 7 but no later - so in that case it would be possible. The rule is that if your device can run the latest iOS, then that it your only option.

Comment: iOS 9 is compatible with the third-gen iPad. However, it may run a little slower--which is to be expected, since it is 3+ years old. To my knowledge, there's no way to only upgrade to an older version of iOS. You'll have to do iOS 9 or stay on iOS 6.