# Upgrade iPhone to current iOS minor release versus going to the new major release version?

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade

When updating my iPhone from settings the only option is iOS 13.X, however I am currently on 12.4.1 and want to simply go to the still current patch version 12.4.3 which came out just a few days ago.

**Is there a way to make the phone go to the minor build update instead of forcing to 13.X?** I want to avoid iOS 13 until a couple of fixes come out that address the major issues plaguing that update, but don't want to have current security holes in my current version.

There was a similar question here: [Upgrade iPad to newer (but not latest) iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211887/upgrade-ipad-to-newer-but-not-latest-ios) but it had to do with a middle jump to an already revoked older version i.e going from 6 to 7, when 8 was the current version, so my question is different in that both versions are currently signed by apple.

Comment: Hi Shawn! What model iPhone do you have?

Comment: @TJLuoma It is a 6S, but I am sure in theory many folks might find this question for any current model, so maybe a great answer is one that can handle them all?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. My guess is that you can do it if:

1. you use iTunes
2. Apple is signing an '.ipsw' file for your iPhone model.

If I was trying to do this, I would look at https://ipsw.me/product/iPhone.

They seem to have a good / easy system for figuring out what is available for which iPhone.

### Update:

If you have a 6s, it does not look like that model is supported. At least that is what I gather from looking at https://ipsw.me/12.4.3.

### Update 2:

https://iosindex.com/iphone also reminded me that there are at least two versions of the iPhone 6s, the "GSM" version and the "everyone else" version. Their pages for each are linked below:

- [iPhone 6s (GSM)](https://iosindex.com/iphone/6s-gsm)
- [iPhone 6s (Global)](https://iosindex.com/iphone/6s-global)

Comment: Do i have to run a backup before doing these steps, or will it simply side-step that and be a normal update?

Comment: Always run a backup.

Comment: Wow thats actually shocking - its a minor security patch to the currently installed version, so if I tried to install it the phone would not verify the version and fail?

Comment: I can't say that for 100% certainty. However, I believe that the security patch was _only_ issued for iPhones which _cannot_ upgrade to iOS 13. You could always try downloading one and see if it will work. I believe iTunes will tell you almost immediately if the .ipsw file will not work for your iPhone model.

Comment: @shawn the ipsw files from ipsw.me are linked directly from the apple website. They are signed by apple and will operate as upgrades unless you opt to do a clean install within iTunes.